# How to approach a job search while in a 3 month contract job?

Tags: new-job, contracts, contract-extension

I am working on-site on a short-term contract, 3 months. From the beginning of application my employer told me that this will be a short-term contract, but the position is with a large company with many perks though.

After struggling for about 6 months to get a desired job, I got this opportunity. Also, the role is not really what I was looking for.

Anyway, I accepted the offer and working with them from past 2 weeks. My contract is for 3 months, I would love to be in the same company but I do not want to continue working on the same position (extend the contract). The other reason I chose this position is because I thought I will manage to get desired role or similar within the same company.

Now, because of the short contract duration, I wondering how should I begin my new job search.

I have few questions:

1. Should I talk to my manager now or wait until 1 or 1.5 months left to apply within the same company? The company has full-time and contract positions.
2. Should I start searching for new opportunities outside the company without informing the manager from tomorrow onwards?
3. Does only a month of contract experience affect my job application if start market my resume?

*Right now, I am more interested in a full-time or long-term contract opportunity.

Comment: Some companies have internal recruiters you can talk to about positions. At my company we have a lot of short/long term contracts, so they have HR resources to allow you to upload your resume and quickly land new positions in the company.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1.Should I talk to my manager now or wait until 1 or 1.5 months left to apply within the same company? The company has FT and contract positions.

The more the manager sees you on the job, the more likely it is that he/she will form an informed opinion on you as a potential employee, and thus for you to get a positive reference

> 2.Should I start searching for new opportunities outside the company without informing the manager from tomorrow onwards?

The fact that you are in a short term contract is known. Informing that you are looking for other opportunities is kinda stating the obvious.

> 3.Does only a month of contract experience affect my job application if start market my resume?

No, if you are able to motivate it (and I think you are)